# Can I use forward declarations inside a DLL?

Tags: c++, function, dll

I have a main project and a DLL project. The main executable links to the DLL.
In the main project I have a function:

```
int func(char *str)
{
    .....
}
```

In the DLL project, I want to use this function. Can I forward declare this function and use it? Like:

```
int func(char *str);

int dllFunc()
{
    ...
    status = func(str);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you adding reference of dll into main project or the reverse?

Comment: i'm adding the reference of the dll to the main project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One (fairly common) way of doing it is to provide a callback from the application, i.e.

In DLL:

```
typedef void (*callback)();

callback my_callback;

void dll_register_callback(callback app_callback) { my_callback = app_callback; }

void do_things() { my_callback(); }
```

In application:

```
void cb() {}

dll_register_callback(cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use forward declaration forward declaration is something different. If you want call some method in dll, you have to use [GetProcAdress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [Implicit linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Anyway, It look that you want to call method placed inside you executable from some DLL, it can be done as far as I know. And it doesn't make much sense, because DLL is designed to be shared between application not main executable.